# How to expose Nginx port

Tags: docker, nginx

I’m learning to set up Nginx using docker.

I created a docker *17.12.0* ce on *16.04* at DigitalOcean.
I followed the [instruction](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx-amplify) to setup .
I run the docker and bind the port using `-p 80:80`. I tried to access but connection is refused.

> `Failed to connect to 139.59.245.108 port 80: Connection refused`

Container info:
[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC66b.png)

Btw, I noticed the messages:

> "ufw" has been enabled. All ports except 22 (SSH), 80 (http) and 443 (https)
>
> have been blocked by default

Comment: What you have posted so far looks OK. Are you sure the IP address is the correct one? Did you check the NGINX logs if there probably was a configuration error?

Comment: `139.59.245.108` is public address, make sure your localhost is visitable! and then try next !

Comment: omg... my localhost is not visitable. What should I do?

Comment: @LeeYeeRun can't you curl localhost:80?

Comment: I think I start to get it... Is it because I didn't install Nginx on host? @lvthillo cannot...

Comment: @Henry I checked Nginx log... no error. And just like FrankAK mentioned, that IP is public address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sure why now it is working... But I guess maybe I need to set `sudo ufw allow 80`, I shut down the docker and start a new docker. Then `docker port <my-container>`, it finally shows up `80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80`